# Application runs batch file which can't delete file

Tags: c#, c++, file, batch-file, visual-studio-2013

I have a C# application which creates a batch file and then runs it. This batch file calls a C++ app which should delete a certain file.

When I run the C# app:

- creating the batch file is ok
- running the batch file is ok
- deleting the file fails.

This is the C++ code and [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388536%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
// Attempt to delete the object from the device
hr = content->Delete(PORTABLE_DEVICE_DELETE_NO_RECURSION,   // Deleting with no recursion
                                        objectsToDelete.Get(), // Object(s) to delete
                                        nullptr);
```

When I run the created batch file from command line it works, so I don't know where the problem could be.

Comment: Are you using a relative path anywhere? The pwd for your batch file may be different when run from the program as opposed to the command line.

Comment: Does your process / child process run in different security context?  Do you get error code / message as to why delete fails?

Comment: @LB2 It should not have any different security context, when I run it with administrator rights, it still doesn't work. I don't have any error code or message.

Comment: Why are you creating and running a batch file instead of just invoking the C++ program directly?

Comment: Does your C# program *open* the file that it later deletes? Windows, unlike most modern systems, doesn't like deleting open files.

Comment: @DropDropped _"I don't have any error code or message"_ - do you have means of getting the value of `hr` from the code block that you posted?  That'll contain the error code that will likely lend clue as to the nature of the misfortune.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I have a relative path to a bat file but I can run it without problem, and also the C++ app starts.

Comment: @dfeuer The file is not opened, I can delete the file when I run the bat directly from cmd, only running bat from C# causes problem.

Comment: @dfeuer I've tried to run it directly from C# but it didn't work, so I made a batch file and found out it works when I call the batch from cmd, but not from C#.

Comment: @LB2 It only shows "s_false"

Comment: Since the batch file did not help, you should go back to the direct approach. Batch files are not particularly known for being easy to debug. I'll second the notion that this sounds like some sort of permission issue, like maybe the C# program (or, more specifically, the C# runtime system) is dropping privileges for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not a complete answer, but the troubleshooting step needed won't fit in the comment, so hence comes as an answer (which I'll amend when more info comes from OP)*:

Per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388536%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) link you posted, if 3rd parameter receives a pointer rather than `nullptr`, then it'll contain specific error information in case of `S_FALSE` return.  This information is pertinent to determining the cause of failure that you're experiencing.

Here is the quote from documentation on meaning of `S_FALSE` from that call:

> At least one object could not be deleted. The ppResults parameter, if specified, contains the per-object error code.

Please amend your code as follows:

```
// Attempt to delete the object from the device
IPortableDevicePropVariantCollection *pResults;
hr = content->Delete(PORTABLE_DEVICE_DELETE_NO_RECURSION,   // Deleting with no recursion
                                        objectsToDelete.Get(), // Object(s) to delete
                                        &pResults);

//TODO: Dump contents of pResults to log/cout/etc., in form objectsToDelete[i]=pResults[i]...
```

OP: Please amend your code to capture `ppResults` and amend your question with information from that structure.